# Wix Installer run msi after main install is done

Tags: wix

I need to run my installer then once done run a 3rd party msi. Figure this would be a simple enough job I am sure I am just missing a flag.  What is wrong with my script;

```
<Binary Id="AnotherApp" SourceFile="C:\Install.msi"/>

<CustomAction Id="RunMSI" BinaryKey="AnotherApp" ExeCommand="" Execute='deferred' Return='asyncNoWait' Impersonate='no'/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='RunMSI' Before='InstallFinalize' />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I see that the C:\Install.msi is included because of the size increase yet it will not run.

FYI I do not want any UI just have it run the install.msi

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Installer has a mutex that prevents this from being possible.  You want to look into a bootstrapper / chainer. For WiX that's called "Burn".